Porting from EF6 with migrations to EF Core 8 with migrations
I'm running EF6 with migrations in .NET 8 Windows project right now. I run my migrations as a part of the startup of my service.
I want to be able to continue EF Core migrations for our existing databases, we got 200+ installations with existing databases so starting from scratch is not an option.
Now, if there always was an existing database available, then just creating an Initial migration with all the create table statements and then just commenting them all out would work great, but I do have the requirement to also be able to create the tables for fresh installations.
Option 1: always use our old version to create the database to its final state before the EF Core port and then update to the new version with initialmigration script commented out / removed.
I'd prefer to not have to do this extra step for every update we do, as all our installations are on-premise in the customers environments and require manual updates but a separate team of people.
Option 2: keep the old migrations in our code base and run it first on startup, but we really want to get rid of EF6 completely so this is not really a great options either.
Now the most obvious solution to me here was that well, cant the create statements just have an ifexists boolean so I could say to only create the tables if they don't already exist in my initial migration. But as far as I can tell, for some reason this is not possible without writing completely manual SQL queries, and I have a lot of tables, so I have no desire to go that route.
Now since that is not supported directly, then I thought the next best thing would be to make a simple select query to check for any existing tables, but no, the sql() method on the migration builder isn't really meant to do reads with so that's not really an options either.
I'm getting a bit frustrated with the whole process, and I'm putting my last hope into SO that maybe someone has found a somewhat elegant way of dealing with this.

Well, check this solution, maybe it will be suitable for you. Also analyse our comments.

What is your target set to.  You could use Core 8 with a target Core 6.  There is a mapping that exists with EF that maps the c# classes/properties to the database tables/fields.  When you upgrade the core version the structure of the mapping will change to match the current Core version.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv That sounds like exactly the issue i'm facing, didnt find thast post, thank you i will look into that one.
